# Display UIview controller as a subview using storyboard IOS7

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

in my application I have a `UIView` object in second view controller. Now I want to display the UIView as a popup or sub view when I click the button from first view controller. Please tell me how to do this? I have seen many solution for the nib files but I didn't find any for storyboard.

I have connected the `IBOulet` of view in my second view controller.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *popview;
```

And i have imported the second view controller in my firstview please tell me how to make this one i have been stuck here for long time please help me out on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use xib file with your storyboard. Do you have to use stroyboard?

Comment: ya since from the begging im using story board i want to use stroyboard

Comment: This is not the ideal way but you can do it like this. Do not use another view controller. Design your storyboard with your modal subview and set it's alpha to 0 in viewDidLoad and set to 1 when you want to display.

Comment: @BoranA sorry boran i'm new for ios can please give some sample code or some clear explaintion will be really help full for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `FirstViewController` which has `UIView *popview`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // you don't want to show PopView
  self.popview.alpha = 0;
}

- (void) showPopView
{
  //you want to show PopView
  self.popview.alpha = 1;
}
```

Comment: what if i want to use more then one uiview and i want to pop on the firstview controller pls help me out

Comment: You just crate UIView that you want in FirstViewController. And setFrame and pop on the FirstViewController if you want

Comment: please tell me how can use more then one uiview for the popmenu im not able to get ur tyring to say

Comment: please tell me how to dismiss the view form the popup

Answer (score 0):

**Try Adding this in your code**

> -(void)viewDidLoad
>
> {
>       popView.hidden=true;
>
> }

**and when ever user clicks an action change the hidden property to false just like**

> -(IBAction)AnyActionPerferformed:(id)sender
>
> {
>
> popView.hidden=false;
>
> }

You can Learn about this from

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]You don't need an extra UIViewController

1. In your storyboard, drag a new UIView to your view controller. (It will be your popup view)
2. Link to your view controller. (`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *popview;`)
3. When you want to hide popview set it's alpha to 0.

Comment: please tell what if i want to view more then one uiview and i want view in the firstview controller

Comment: i have tried with two uiview its just overlopping on each other please to me how to resolve this one

Comment: That's why we set alpha to 0. It makes the view invisible.

Comment: tell me how to dismiss the uiview from popup